# Plugin qTranslatePlus with Finch Theme in WordPress and Languages in Topbar

Tags: plugins, wordpress, qtranslate

I have a problem when working with Finch theme in WordPress and the plugin qTranslatePlus (for a webpage having different languages). The problem is that the languages are available in the sidebar, whereas I would like them to be in a topbar. What could be done? Perhaps the plugin or the theme should be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every theme works with all qTranslate options.
I know that "Twenty Thirteen" theme works,
but it is very difficult to find else.
Good news! The new version of qTranslate, which works with WP 4+: https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/
They promise that all the settings will remain with no harm.